# Showing Images on a layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview

I am having this code and require the following position of images.But as I used Relative Layout, & the Images are not aligning properly in all the devices, Some are overlapping the images.
**Edit: Main Requirement: In my requirement, I want to click the Green Cap. So, if I press red cap , that ImageView will be disappeared.So, the remaining two images must be at their same place.So If I use layout_weight, it is covering the remaining two images to the remaining space.**
How can I get the best output for this requirement.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#657383"
android:orientation="horizontal" >



<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView3"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name" />
```

[image: Model Image]

Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `LinearLayout` with `android:layout_weight` attribute. set the layout_weight attribute same for all ImageView. By this all ImageView will take same space. Also use    `android:scaleType="fitXY"`

for example if I consider editing your code.. .( just writting here so there may be minor mistakes)

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView3"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"       
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name" />
```

Comment: an horizontal LinearLayour with layout_widht="0dip". +1

Comment: simply use android:visibility="gone" when you need to make it invisible

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
android:layout_toRightOf="" // specify id of image-view
android:layout_toLeftOf=""  //  specify id of image-view
```

in the values field u need to specify the id of image view

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#657383"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
         android:layout_weight="1"
          android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_weight="1"
         android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Use View.INVISIBLE instead of View.GONE

Answer (score 0):

The `RelativeLayout` is redundant. You can just set the linear layout to center:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="#657383"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <ImageView
        ...
```

Note the extra lines `android:layout_gravity="center"` and `android:gravity="center"`

Answer (score 0):

If you want images not to overlap, you have to use smaller images on devices with smaller screen. You may use drawable-large-*dpi and xlarge-*dpi or drawable-sw***dp-*dpi folders for bigger images and drawable-*dpi for phones.

Btw. You don't need LinearLayout wrapping everything.